# Codeigniter GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have:

```
$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(prod_poster, poster2, poster3, poster4, poster5, poster6, poster7)');
```

And I have error for this and shows sql query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(prod_poster, `poster2`, `poster3`, `poster4`, `poster5`, `poster6`, `poster7)`
```

it's problem because of ->>>>  **`** near poster7. this symbol must be inside bracket. whyc codeigniter do like this? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing:

```
$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(prod_poster, poster2, poster3, poster4, poster5, poster6, poster7)', false);
```

If you pass false as the second argument of `select()`, it won't try to protect your query by adding in backticks (like it has in your example).

See: https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: @alexpls nice answer. Your Helper link to the CI documentation is not working please update that.

Comment: @always-a-learner Woah it's been a while since I answered this, looks like the CI docs have changed a lot since then. Updated that link for you :)